# Facebook FQL: Getting pages a user likes, which at least one of their friends also likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is this possible? I tried one thing which does not work:

```
SELECT name 
FROM page 
WHERE page_id IN (
    SELECT page_id
    FROM page_fan
    WHERE uid = me()
    AND page_id IN (
        SELECT page_id
        FROM page_fan
        WHERE uid IN (
            SELECT uid2 
            FROM friend 
            WHERE uid1 = me()
        )
    )
)
```

Do I need to get the pages a user likes and then loop through them all, checking for friend likes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those that have answered this question. Unfortunately all of the solutions are very slow, and they do not obtain all of the pages (I'm guessing due to timeout).

What I did is get all of the user's pages. I then filtered these down to the pages I am interested in. After that I look to see if friends have liked the pages:

```
likes = fql("SELECT name, page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me())", access_token);
pages = []
for x in xrange(len(likes)):

    # Check that the page is an occasion

    conn.execute("SELECT 1 FROM occasionPageIds WHERE pageid = " + str(likes[x]["page_id"]) + " LIMIT 1");

    if len(conn.fetchall()):

        # Check that friends like this

        friend_likes = fql("SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = " + str(likes[x]["page_id"]) + " AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())", access_token);

        if len(friend_likes):
            pages.append(likes[x]["page_id"])
```

So you must filter the pages before checking if friends like the page, unless you want to wait a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

This FQL will do the trick:

```
select name from page where page_id in (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN 
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me ())) and page_id in
(select page_id from page_fan where uid = me())
```

Hope it will work with you ,,,

Comment: Hi. This unfortunately returns no data for me: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20name%20from%20page%20where%20page_id%20in%20(SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_fan%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%0A(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%20()))%20and%20page_id%20in%0A(select%20page_id%20from%20page_fan%20where%20uid%20%3D%20me())

Comment: It works will with me actually ,,, are you sure that the token has user_likes and friends_likes permissions

Comment: Yes thank you, that was the problem! I didn't realise I needed to request another access token.

Comment: Welcome my friend ,,, you stopped my heart when you said it returned no data... Good luck mate

Comment: I decided to give you the bounty since the answer was slightly quicker and more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Using a multi query I was able to achieve this using the following query. However it does take some time.

```
  {"friend_likes":"SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid in(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1= me())","joints":"SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id in(SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me() AND page_id in(SELECT page_id FROM #friend_likes))"}
```

The above query gets all your friends likes and then matches them up to your likes. The issue is, the more friends you have the longer it takes to run (as it gets all their likes obviously). I tried to optimise this by getting all my likes, and then only getting friends likes from that list of page_ids, however for some reason this always returns an empty set. It seems like for this to work in 1 query, you have to go the long way round as it were.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll try this out tomorrow. I'll keep the bounty open to wait for more efficient implementations, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

FQL turns into a snail or timeouts for any subquery greater than two. Also I am not even sure distinct page_ids are selected (each user likes the same page how is it filtered?). So when you do the set operation, it most likely wouldn't work. Just do two queries.

- One that gets your list of page_ids like by friends 
  `"SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())"`
- Then another that just pulls your likes
  `"SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me())"`

Now put this in a batch just so we get both data sets in one go

```fql
fql?q={"userpages":"SELECT page_id 
                    FROM page_fan 
                    WHERE uid=me()",
       "friendpages":"SELECT page_id 
                      FROM page_fan 
                      WHERE uid IN 
                      (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())"}
```

From here you will have most likely a really huge list and a small one

Let's say in Python,

```
>>> len(data['data'][0]['fql_result_set'])
4505
>>> len(data['data'][1]['fql_result_set'])
85
```

We need to do two things here,

- get the interesection set
- remove duplicates

Now this will end up being trivial on this level in terms of filters and lambdas.... but we pretty much destroy any usefulness of the data. We just have a set of page less the actual friends that actually liked them! How do we verify?

Well, now thinking about it, it's best to keep the user id fields from our API calls, then we would clump ids together. A simple example in Python

```python
>>> pages = {}
>>> for p in a0:
...     for q in a1:
...         if p['page_id'] == q['page_id']:
...             pid =  p['page_id']
...             if pid in pages:
...                 pages[pid].append(p['uid'])
...             else:
...                 pages[pid] = [q['uid']]
...                 pages[pid].append(p['uid'])
```

`pages` will give me a dict with each key having a list of ids as a value.

Then we can confirm with just looking at a browser dump of the API call and crtl-F. Looking at the actual pages will not be a valid test because of API privacy restrictions of friends who disable 3rd party applications. We want to match the occurrences in the JSON response.

Comment: Well I can confirm this works for me, though I need to compare the solutions to see which one is faster. I'm not sure downloading all of that data will be very efficient but we will see.

Answer (score 0):

My python code spends about 36.8938140869 seconds to query, i have 2277 friends and 2086 page liked(Facebook have 5000 limit for friends+page connection). I think query 100 page_ids once should be ok.

```
import urllib, urllib2, json, time
t0 = time.time()
a = "SELECT name, page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me())"
AC = "USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q="+urllib.quote_plus(a)+"&format=json-strings&access_token="+AC
print url
o = urllib2.urlopen(url)
r = o.read()
j = json.loads(r)['data']
page_list = []
page_info_dict = {}
for jj in j:
    page_list.append(jj["page_id"])
    page_info_dict[jj["page_id"]] = jj["name"]
map_list =[]
st = 0

for i, e in enumerate(page_list):
    t1 = time.time()
    pp = ",".join(page_list[st:st+100])
    print pp, type(pp)
    a = "SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE page_id IN ("+pp+") and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())"
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q="+urllib.quote_plus(a)+"&format=json-strings&access_token="+AC
    print url
    o = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    r = o.read()
    j = json.loads(r)
    t2 = time.time()
    print t2- t1
    for jj in j['data']:
        map_list.append(jj["page_id"])
    if st>len(page_list):
        break
    else:
        st+=100
mutual_liks_page_id = list(set(map_list))
for page_id in mutual_liks_page_id:
    print page_info_dict.get(page_id, "")
print "Total time: ", time.time()-t0, " seconds"
```